# When to create new table for relation instead of adding an Array or utilising a data structure in general

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it more cost-effective for the query plan to use a data structure, for example array or list, to store instances in many-to-many relationship instead of creating a new table to store the instances. For example, if I am designing a car pooling app, and I have table rides, instead of creating table ride_reservation that contain each passenger, I can add an attribute of type array in table ride to store passengers

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not more cost-effective, but definitely possible.  You would have to try alternative solutions on *your* data.

Comment: Thanks for replying Gordon, I though the array might be a better option because you will search only for passengers relevant to the trip instead of going through passengers belonging to different trips as in table where the array will contain passengers related to the trip only. or I am missing something ?

Comment: @ m.mashaly . . . You are missing that SQL is designed to handle tables and has multiple algorithms for processing them.  It has optimizations in the form of indexes and partitioning as well.  I'm not saying that arrays are *not* faster, only that you have to try on your data and your queries.  There are no doubt examples of queries that are both faster and slower with a non-normalized approach.

Comment: Yeah got it, thank you again. @GordonLinoff